# StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava

Tags: java, scala, playframework, unicode-escapes

I am getting `\u1F44A\u1F44A` where i am expecting `\ud83d\udc4d\ud83d\udc4d`.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils

val data=""

println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(data))//\u1F44A\u1F44A

println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\u1F44A\u1F44A"))//ὄAὄA

println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\ud83d\udc4d\ud83d\udc4d"))//
```

how i get this `\ud83d\udc4d\ud83d\udc4d`    ?

Answer (score 1):

Unicode:    U+1F44D

UTF-16BE:   D8 3D DC 4D

you can see that [1F44D uincode table](https://unicode-table.com/cn/1F44D/)

So

```
println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(data))//\u1F44A\u1F44A
println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\ud83d\udc4d\ud83d\udc4d"))//
```

Maybe the IDE console window uses utf-16be？
Eclipse can set the console window to use utf-16be or other

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Apache Commons-Lang 3.0 and 3.1. I think it's fixed in 3.2.0, so upgrade to 3.2.x or 3.3.x.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that we need the Apache Commons Library for this. We can easily achieve this in Scala using the standard libraries available.

```scala
val data: String =""

println(System.getProperty("file.encoding", "No encoding")))
// prints UTF-8

println(data.map(x => "\\u%04x".format(x.toInt)).mkString)
// prints \ud83d\udc4d\ud83d\udc4d
```

You can set your encoding by setting `file.encoding` parameter in the JVM config.

Tested on [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org) for Scala version 2.13.3.